# Confused by jQuery not found when I know it's there

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made sure to verify that my reference to the jQuery is correct like so.

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log($(this));
};
```

I get to see non-null value. But when I try any of the below (the part above commented out), I get the error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
//$(document).ready(function () { alert("ready"); });
$(window).onload(function () { alert("onload"); });
```

I'm confused how it can be defined and not defined at the same time. After some googling I've found several code samples [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807903/1525840) and as far I can see, it's not a syntax in the file.

The markup is like so.

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="Stuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</body>
```

I've seen in the default (and working) template for MVC.NET under Razor that they do `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` in the head, and then `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` at the bottom of the body. I figured that I could follow the same pattern. Evidently, I failed. Sorry for being unclear. Incorrect diagnostics due to ignorance.

Comment: jQuery does not have onload-method, that code should never work.

Comment: what is the other pieces of code with your ```window.onload```? Did you used strict mode (```'use strict';```)?

Comment: Open console in your web and put '$'. Did you get **function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}** ?

Comment: Be aware that $ and $$ exist on Chrome even though jQuery doesn't.

Comment: I bet you included jQuery after you included the code above.

Comment: Can you show how your script tags are included? I think it is key to solving your question.

Comment: @Esko I toolk it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/807903/1525840)

Comment: @Louy I'm not using WordPress. Also, I don't understand your edit to my question. It actually changed what's being asked and what's been done to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Itipacs I have $ defined. It says: "function jQuery()" in FF and in Cr: "function ( selector, context ) {// The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); }"

Comment: @Beri Yes, see comment above.

Comment: @engineer Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: @epascarello I bet so too, based on the info. I updated the question.

Comment: @scunliffe Yes, please see edit.

Comment: And that is your problem. It is like trying to eat a pizza before you make it. Move your script below the jQuery bundle.

Comment: @epascarello Easier said than done. I've moved thing around and Now I have `@RenderBody() @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @Scripts.Render("~/Stuff.js")` but still the same misbehavior... Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `script` tag for jQuery in the wrong place. It's **after** the `script` tag for the code you've shown, whereas it should be **before** it.

The reason it can be both defined and undefined is that the **timing** is different. Those references to `$` are at very different times:

This one:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log($(this));
};
```

happens **really late** in the page load cycle, after all the HTML is parsed, all of the `script` tags processed, all the images loaded, etc., when the `load` event on `window` finally fires.

These:

```
//$(document).ready(function () { alert("ready"); });
$(window).onload(function () { alert("onload"); });
```

happen **immediately** when the parser reaches the script block they're in, hands off to the JavaScript engine, and the JavaScript engine runs that code.

So this would work:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    console.log($(this));
};
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

but this fails:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(funtion() {
    alert("ready");
});
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

This works regardless:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(funtion() {
    alert("ready");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I got it. The question's been answered. Now, I still don't get it to work, despite moving to `@RenderBody() @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @Scripts.Render("~/Stuff.js")`. Is it a Razor specific question? If so, I'll that separately. The way I see, it should render just the order you're suggesting.

Comment: @AndyJ: Bizarre. I would expect that too. If you look at the generated page in the browser, what do you see? Are there any attributes on the `script` tags? (There are two attributes, `async` and `defer`, that each change how scripts are processed. But I'd be shocked if Razor were rendering script tags with them unless you told it to.)

Comment: No such attributes, just as you predicted. And the order in the document is as expected. I'll it over to the other question. Maybe someone will see something.